# classList "add" working but "toggle" is not

Tags: javascript

An extremely simple to-do list, where you highlight each item as your mouse is over it, and you check as done as you click on them...
Done through class adding a toggling, however on click the class is not applied (or applied but the text doesn't change?)

Could you help me? Seems an awfully dumb error on my part I'm sure:

https://jsfiddle.net/gLdjm8o1/

OR here as well:

```js
var hover = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < hover.length; i++) {

  hover[i].addEventListener ("mouseover", function() {
  this.classList.add("greener");
  });

  hover[i].addEventListener ("mouseout", function() {
  this.classList.remove("greener");
  });

  hover[i].addEventListener ("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("done");
  });   
}
```

```css
.greener {
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
};

.done {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Feed loratadina to you</li>
  <li>Create a black crate</li>
  <li>Sleep more than 7 hours</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your click handler tries to toggle a class called `"baby"`, but the CSS shown doesn't define a class with that name.

Comment: just a typo, I meant "done" class, edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is being applied, but your CSS is invalid; remove the semicolon here:

```css
.greener {
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}; /* ← this one */
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLdjm8o1/1/)

Comment: It was not a nightmare...indeed the semicolon monster attacked me, thanks for this!

Comment: Should I delete my question/post as irrelevant since its just a semicolon, or leave as is for the community? Thanks